# Return boolean from string search

Tags: powershell, where-clause, select-string

I'm trying to return TRUE from searching Get-ComplianceSearch's output for 'Completed'. My code below is a simple wait loop. But I don't think I'm returning the value correctly because the loop never finishes. I'm fairly new to PowerShell. Please assist or direct.

I'm using Powershell Core 7.1. There are no errors but the Search-String condition never returns TRUE.

```
    try {
        $timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        while (($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and (-not (Get-ComplianceSearch - 
Identity $searchName | Select-String 'Completed' -SimpleMatch -Quiet))) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $RetryInterval
        $totalSecs = [math]::Round($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 0)
        Write-Verbose -Message "Still waiting for action to complete after [$totalSecs] 
seconds..."
        }
    $timer.Stop()
    if ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -gt $Timeout) {
        throw 'Action did not complete before timeout period.'
    } else {
        Write-Verbose -Message 'Action completed before timeout period.'
    }
} catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
}
```

(This is the expected output of the command Get-ComplianceSearch)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you don't want to use `Select-String` here (although you *can*, see @mklement0's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866442/584676), looking at object properties is usually preferred). That is returning an object and you want to check the `Status` property for `"Completed"`. Make the following change to the `-not` subexpression:

```
(-not (Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity $searchName | Where-Object {
  $_.Status -eq 'Completed'
}))
```

The above can be on one line but I broke it up for readability.

---

Basically, `Select-String` looks for content in strings. If you are looking for a particular value of an object property however, you can use `Where-Object` to test for a condition and return any objects matching that condition. In this case, we want to return any object that have a `Status` of `'Completed'`, so we can negate that in the `if` statement.

---

You (or others) might be wondering how this works since `Where-Object` returns matching objects, but not booleans. The answer is "truthiness". PowerShell objects are "truthy", which means anything can be evaluated as a `[bool]`.

The following values evaluate to `$false` in most cases. I've included some gotchas to watch out for when relying on "truthy" values:

- A numeric value of `0`

  - A string value of `0` evaluates as `$true`
- Empty arrays
- Empty strings

  - A whitespace-only string or strings consisting only of non-printable characters evaluates as `$true`
- `$false`

  - A string value of `False` evaluates as `$true`

Most everything else will evaluate to `$true`. This is also why comparison operators are syntactically optional when checking whether a variable is `$null` or not. Although there are times when an explicit value check is a good idea as comparison operators compare the actual values instead of only whether the variable "is" or "isn't".

How does this apply to the expression above then? Simple. `if` statements, always treat the condition expression as a `[bool]`, no conversion required. In addition, logical operators and conditional operators also imply a boolean comparison. For example, `$var = $obj` assigns `$obj` to `$var`, but
`$var = $obj -eq $obj2` or `$var = $obj -and $obj2` will assign `$true` or `$false`.

---

So knowing the above, if `Where-Object` returns nothing, it's `$false`. If it returns a tangible object, it's `$true`.

Answer (score 2):

**[Bender the Greatest's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866444/45375) shows a *better alternative* to using `Select-String`**, because OO-based filtering that queries specific properties is always more robust than searching string representations.

That said, **for quick-and-dirty *interactive* searches, being able to search through a command's *formatted display output* can be handy**, and, unfortunately, **`Select-String` does *not* do that by default**.

---

**As for what you tried**:

To make your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) work, you need to insert [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) `-Stream` before the `Select-String` call, so as to ensure that the *for-display* representation is sent through the pipeline, line by line.

```sh
# `oss` can be used in lieu of `Out-String -Stream` in PSv5+.
# `sls` can be used in lieu of `Select-String`.
Get-ComplianceSearch | Out-String -Stream | Select-String 'Completed' -SimpleMatch -Quiet
```

Note:

- If you want to search a for-display representation *other than the default one*, you can insert a `Format-*` cmdlet call before the `Out-String -Stream` segment; e.g.
  `Get-Item / | Format-List * | Out-String -Stream | Select-String ...` would search through a *list* representation of all properties of the object output by `Get-Item`.

Perhaps surprisingly, **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) does *not* search an input object's *for-display* representation**, as you would see it in the *console*, using the rich formatting provided by PowerShell's [display-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml).

Instead, it **performs *simple `.ToString()` stringification***, whose results are often unhelpful and cannot be relied upon to include the values of *properties*. (E.g.,
`@{ foo = 'bar' } | Select-String foo` does *not* work as intended; it is equivalent to
`@{ foo = 'bar' }.ToString() | Select-String foo` and therefore to
`'System.Collections.Hashtable' | Select-String foo`

Arguably, **`Select-String` should always have defaulted to searching through the input objects' formatted string representations**:

- That there is demand for this behavior is evidenced by the fact that PowerShell versions 5 and above (both editions) ship with the `oss` convenience function, which is a wrapper for `Out-String -Stream`.
- [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146) asks that the current behavior of `Select-String` be changed to search the for-display string representations *by default*.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. It is amazing helpful.

Comment: I also learned something, I never knew how or what defined the default display of certain PowerShell objects in the console. `for-display` seems to be the key word here. Also never thought to pipe an object to `Out-String -Stream` to search that same visual representation

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Ccorock; please also see my update.

Comment: Nice. I wish they'd alias `Select-String` to `ss` out of the box too, but I guess I can kind of see why they'd stay away from that one.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest :) `sls` is the built-in alias, though note that its name is irregularly formed: since `sc` is the official alias prefix for `Select-*` commands, it should have been `scs`.