# Powershell Select-string text file

Tags: powershell, select-string

I am fairly new to Powershell and have run into a bit of a pickle.
I have created a list of all files in multiple directories with their extensions with the aim of doing a string pattern match to retrieve the files (with their extension and matching string pattern) that I am interested in.

```
$directory = 'c:\test', 'd:\test\test'
$files = Get-ChildItem -file $directory -recurse | Select-Object Fullname, extension
$patterns = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Patterns.txt' 
$files | Select-String -pattern $patterns | Select-Object Pattern, Line
```

When I run a Select-String to match, my output has @{Fullname = C:\test\test0001.txt; Extension = .txt} etc.

Is there a way I can get the output to look more like the below and export it as a CSV file?

| Pattern | Fullname | Extension |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | C:\test\test00001.txt | .txt |
| 00002 | D:\test\test\00002.docx | .docx |

Comment: Try `Format-Table` and `ConvertTo-CSV`.

Comment: @HsuPu, use of `Format-*` cmdlets in order to output _data_ is the wrong approach - they're for _for-display formatting_ only.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, which combines use of the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
Get-ChildItem -PipelineVariable file -File $directory -Recurse |
  Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Patterns.txt') | 
    Select-Object Pattern,
                  @{ Name='Fullname';  Expression = { $file.FullName } },                  
                  @{ Name='Extension'; Expression = { $file.Extension } }
```

Pipe the above to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) as needed.

- `-PipelineVariable file` stores each file-info object emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) in variable `$file`, allowing it to be referenced in a script block in a later pipeline segment.
- The expressions defining the values of the calculated properties in the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call reference the file-info object stored in pipeline variable `$file` in order to create output objects that combine the `Pattern` property from the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) output objects with property values from the input file at hand.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your primary problem was your attempt to pipe *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances) to `Select-String`, which causes the latter to search through the *stringified representation* of the custom objects (which yields a string  like `'@{Fullname = ...; extension = ...}'`, as shown in your question<sup>[1]</sup>) - rather than treating them as representing *files* whose *content* you want to search.

  - To achieve that, you must use *file-info objects* ([`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances) as input, as directly emitted by `Get-ChildItem`.
  - For the sake of completeness:

    - If your non-file-info input objects have a property reflecting the file path of interest, such as in your case, you *can* make this work, namely via a [*delay-bind script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) passed to `Select-String`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter:

      `$files | Select-String -LiteralPath { $_.Fullname } ...`
    - Similarly, if your custom objects had a `LiteralPath` (or `PSPath` or, in PowerShell (Core) 7+, `LP`) property containing the file path of interest, piping it `Select-String` *should* work as-is, because that property's value *should* automatically bind to the `-LiteralPath` parameter (this mechanism, in fact, is how `System.IO.FileInfo` instances bind to `-LiteralPath` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375) for an explanation); however, as of PowerShell 7.2.2, this appears to be *broken* with `Select-String`, specifically: see [GitHub issue #17188](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17188).
- The secondary problem is that your `Select-Object` call operates only on the output objects emitted by `Select-String`, which are [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances, which do not have `.Fullname` and `.Extension` properties.

---

<sup>[1] Note that this string representation is the result of simple `.ToString()` stringification; it is *not* the rich representation you would see in the console, courtesy of PowerShell's for-display output formatting system. This surprising behavior is discussed in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866442/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This feels wrong somehow, but it works. I have a feeling there's a better way to convert the Line property to a hashtable object, but I tried both Invoke-Expression and ConvertFrom-StringData with no success.

```
$directory = 'c:\test', 'd:\test\test'   
$files = Get-ChildItem -File $directory | Select-Object FullName, Extension
$exportObj = $files | Select-String -Pattern $patterns | Select-Object Pattern, Line | %{
    $line = $_.Line -replace "[@,{,}]","" -split ";"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            Pattern=$_.Pattern
            FullName=($line[0] -split "=")[1]
            Extension=($line[1] -split "=")[1]
        }
    }
$exportObj | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```